# Set up nameserver with multiple domains

Tags: domain, nameserver

i have a dedicated with a primary ip and domain name. I added nameserver settings for this domain, and mx records.

n1.mydomain.com
ns2.mydomain.com

etc.

Now i want to add more domain with websites to my server. Now what is the best way to do this.

1. Should i add the domain, and use the mydomain.com nameserver settings.
2. Shoudl i add the domain and create his own nameserver.

I should add the websites have to be optimized for best performance, fastest load time.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like with webservers, the answer is "depends".  You will need to monitor the amount of queries hitting your DNS servers to determine if you need to move to suggestion 2.

On, the other hand, for most domains, two nameservers will be plenty.  The bigger bottleneck will be the web traffic, not the DNS responses.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But is it even possible to have 2 nameservers running on the same ip adresses

Comment: You can have tons of FQDNs that point to the same IP, which is running your nameserver.  That server just needs to know about all of those domains.

Personally, I just have all my domains use ns.myprimarydomain.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. So i can just enable DNS on my prim adres. And on all the other domains i dont enable dns. And have my registar point the domain names to the prim name server?

Comment: Sort of... your prim DNS needs to be authoritative for all domains that the registrar is pointing at you.  In named.conf (*nix world), you would have section/file for each domain.  In windows, you would have one forward lookup zone for each domain you want pointed to your DNS server(s)

Answer (score 0):

In most circumstances even the smallest nameserver can serve many domains without breaking a sweat. This is for several reasons, including the fact that DNS queries are tiny and results are cached on every resolver that query your nameserver (so it's not getting repeatedly queried from the same locations, ISPs, ...etc). I'd recommend putting the additional domains on the same existing nameserver(s), at least for now.

Loading a website at your domain will likely result in a single query to your nameserver from the person loading the site (technically that person's DNS server) and their resolver will cache the result for the subsequent lookups as the page loads. Unless the DNS for the domain is broken or the server is severely bogged down for some reason, the DNS lookup will have very little impact on the web page loading time.

Answer (score 0):

we run 100's of domains on a primary nameserver then use our hosting providers dns for 2ndary

our setup is to make a /etc/bind/zones dir and put all the zone files in there

then set the linkage up to point to that zone file from inside the /etc/bind/named.local

---

to answer you question about two nameservers on same machine:

you can have two different primary nameservers running on same server
for instance you can have both of these pointing to same ip and use either or as the primary nameserver 
ns.domain.com
ns.domain.net

but

you cant have your primary and secondary nameservers pointing to same ip
for instance if these were your primary and secondary, they would have to be on differnet ips at the very least and usually not on same subnet
ns.domain.com
ns2.domain.com